# How could this generate a mean of zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, neural-network

I am following [[this](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/)] tutorial about neural networks, and he talks about having a `mean of 0` with this code:

`syn0 = 2*numpy.random.random((3,1)) - 1`

How could this generate a mean of zero? The code to test it [[here](https://repl.it/FRyE/1)]. What is the purpose of multiplying it by 2 and subtracting 1? There are 3 inputs and 1 output, thats why it's of size `(3,1)`

Comment: I think it's just a 3 rows one column array  with null esperance. E(syn0)=2*E(array)-E(1)=2*(1/2)-1=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.random.random`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html)  draws numbers from a uniform distribution over [0, 1). The expected value (mean) of this distribution is `1/2 * (a + b)`  where `a`  and `b` are lower and upper boundaries (0 and 1). So the expected value is 0.5.

```
np.random.random(10**6).mean()
Out: 0.50038769812077288
```

This makes the expected value of `syn0` zero (`2 * 0.5 - 1 = 0`).

Comment: But for 3 numbers, the mean could be off by a lot and not zero, right?

Comment: And why didn't he just subtract 0.5?

Comment: Yes, you'll approach to the actual mean as you increase the sample size. For a very small sample size like this, the mean of the random numbers can be anything between 0 and 1. Subtracting 0.5 is also a possibility if you only consider the mean. They would generate different distributions with the same mean.

Comment: Last question: why didn't he just make them all `0`? Is there a benefit to them being random?